# horizontal autoscroll datagridview c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am not able to scroll horizontally in datagridview which throws the error "**FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex property cannot be set to an invisible column.**" I am binding a datatable to the datagridview and have set few columns invisible. Not sure what causes the issue.The vertical scroll is working without any issue. I have not added the scroll bars programatically and the datgridview is set inside a panel with dock property set to fill. Any specific reason for the issue,please state it down

```
  if (hashcharges.ContainsKey("1"))
        {
            if (dataGridViewSummary1.Columns.Contains("Charge1"))
            {
                dataGridViewSummary1.Columns["Charge1"].HeaderText = hashcharges["1"].ToString().ToLower();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridViewSummary1.Columns["Charge1"].Visible = false;
        }
```

This is how i set the column invisble after binding datatable with datagridview.The error is not thrown in the same form instead it is shown in program.cs file.

Comment: Can you post some code and mark the line where the error occurs, please?

Comment: Well, the error is clear, FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex is set to an invisible column, just set it to a visible one.

Comment: I cannot set it to visible column since i didnt want the user to view it

Answer (score 0):

You can set [DataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingcolumnindex(v=vs.110).aspx) property to the index of the column that is the first column displayed. In your case definitely not the first one, because it is hidden.